# I updated my android studio to the newest version and it doesn't start now and I get an internal errors

Tags: java, android

After running the android studio this error appears and the android studio stops.

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors() 
[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

Comment: it says `Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues` have you tried doing that ?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't understand anything useful to solve my problems.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many times; finally, I was able to solve the problem by deleting the

```
.local/share/google/AndroidStudioPreview4.2
```